# .htaccess question - the [L] flag any way to simplify

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, flags

I usually use MVC routing but I have to work on a site with non MVC and need to add a new feature.

Here is my commnads which works:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/why-am-using-htaccess/$ viewBlog.php?blogHook=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) blogs.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?hookName=$1
```

My issue is I have to put the [L] flag on everything above for it to work.  I want to basically issue a flag to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?hookName=$1
```

That basically says do everything above but the last one is the fallback.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

before your last rule. The first rules rewrote the requested url to a valid (php) file which can be accessed, so the conditions will turn to false. If no rules matched before, but the requested url is a valid file yet (such as an image), this rule isn't processed too.

You should also omit the slash in the last rule: ^(.*)/$, because otherwise this rule only rewrites urls with an ending slash.

Comment: "You should also omit the slash in the last rule" - Not necessarily. That trailing slash also means it won't catch static resources (images, scripts, valid files), without the "expensive" filesystem check.